# GCP Load Balancer for 2 SPAs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-load-balancer

I have the following setup on Google Cloud Storage

BucketA - Contains a React SPA
BucketB - Contains another React SPA

Load Balancer with 2 backends BucketA and BucketB

I want the following

`www.mysite.com` to go to `BucketA`
`www.mysite.com/app` to go to `BucketB`
`Default` to `BucketA`

I tried the following amongst other settings and i can not get it to work

- `All unmatched default` to `BucketA`
- `Host=mysite.com` `Paths= /*` `Backend=BucketA`
- `Host=mysite.com` `Paths= /app /app/*` `Backend=BucketB`

That did not work. Does the solution lie in `Traffic Director`?

Comment: Have you looked at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website ?  Specifically https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#lb-backend ?

Comment: What's is doesn't work? The `/app` pages? All of them? What's the error message?